# CSS pseudo-element size issue

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Please tell me why `:before` pseudo-element doesn't behave like a regular `img` in this case:

[image]

Left one is `div` with an `img` inside and `img`'s width and height are equals 100% . Right one is `div` with `:before` and `:before`'s width and height are also 100% , but effect is different!

(I know i can use a `background-image` workaround , but what is wrong with `:pseudo` when its `content` property is `url()` ?)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tp9JG/4/

Comment: I am befuddled by this, but it looks like `width` and `height` simply does not apply to images inserted through `url()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978807

Comment: @xec thanks to Tomzan , found this: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Nov/thread.html#msg451

Comment: Also note that you cannot control `width` if you chose to make `display: inline;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot control the size of the image when specifying it through content,
But you can if you're using it as background:

```
.with_before:before{
    content:'';
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAAFj.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tp9JG/8/)

And for your question why we can't style generated content:
We can't because generated content is rendered into a generated box, and you **can** style that box, but not the content.

references:

1. [check this post](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Nov/0462.html)
2. [another lengthy discussion on this subject](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Nov/thread.html#msg451)

please notice that different browsers show very different behaviors.