# An object with fixed sizes inside :before or :after pseudo element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I know I can do something like:

```
.container:after {
    content: url("../images/img.png");
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Is there anyway I can achieve similar functionality without referencing to an image? What i need is pseudo element to change its height based on width of parent element (.container in example). Pretty similar to an image with `width:100%;` `height: auto;`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want on `:after` instead of the image?

Comment: Any at all. I just need fixed proportions of the pseudo element. So that when the width of .container will change, the height of :after will change accordingly to some proportion.

Comment: I mean if i use image in :after it has some proportions so the pseudo element will have it, but i don't really need an image.

Comment: I need pseudo element to take full width of .container, and have some height that depends of container width. ie when container width is 100px - pseudo element height is 200px, when container width is 50px, pseudo element height should be 100px.. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978807/can-you-apply-a-width-to-a-before-after-pseudo-element-contenturlimage):

> In the meantime, if you want to be able to resize the `:after` pseudo-element and the image that's generated, you will need to apply it as a background image instead and — assuming browser support isn't an issue — use `background-size` along with `width` and `height` to scale it (based on the understanding that those properties apply to the pseudo-element box instead).

So, instead of

```
content: url("../images/img.png");
```

use

```
background-image: url("../images/img.png");
background-size: cover;
```

(or the shorthand, `background: url("../images/img.png") 0 0 / cover`)

As for scaling your pseudo-element proportionally, I think you should be able to accomplish this using the `padding-bottom` trick. For an image with a ratio of 1:2, `padding-bottom: 200%` seems to work in this example:

```css
.container {
  border: thick solid;
  margin: 1em;
}

.large.container { width: 100px; }
.small.container { width: 50px; }

.container::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x200) 0 0 / cover;
  padding-bottom: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="large container"></div>
<div class="small container"></div>
```

Comment: How this addresses "pseudo element with height based on width of parent element" ?

Comment: Funny thing, just last week I proposed addition of `height:width(100%)` feature at W3C styles: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Mar/0161.html

Comment: @c-smile: The OP talks about proportions in the comments under the question. Also, I saw that thread - anything that proposes having a property value be based on another property value on the same element is bound to fail because someone is going to ask you how you expect `width: height(100%); height: width(100%)` to compute, where the two properties have a cyclic dependency on each other.

Comment: Well it's perfect! BoltClock, thanks man, you saved my day..Though it is still an image, i think we have no other options. Thanks a lot.
 c-smile if we set width of pseudo element to 100% that do the trick. We now have width of parent element and the proportions of image .. ie any proportions

Comment: @BoltClock Read my proposal there.  `width: height(100%)` is not acceptable - will evaluate to  `width: auto`.

Comment: @BoltClock sorry I'm new here and can't upvote yet, the padding trick did the trick) Wish we'd have some clean tools in css inventary to achieve this. Thanks again!