# CSS: Using data attribute as content URL

Tags: css, css-content

So I have a div that allows me to display a QR code of the current page URL:

```
.page-qr:before {
  content: url(https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=100x100&chl=<?php echo current_page(); ?>?choe=UTF-8);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

And used like:

```
<div class="page-qr"> </div>
```

Obviously, to get the current URL on-the-fly, I have to put this CSS styling in the `<head>` of my page. I am trying to move it to the stylesheet.

I had the idea to use a data attribute to specify the URL:

```
<div class="page-qr" data-url="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=100x100&chl=<?php echo current_page(); ?>?choe=UTF-8"> </div>
```

So, my question is, is it possible to double up the usage of `content:url()` and `attr(data-url)` in the stylesheet?

```
.page-qr:before {
  content: url(attr(data-url)); /* Doesn't work, but you get the idea */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Note that the height and width properties here don't actually resize the inserted image. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978807/can-you-apply-a-width-to-a-before-after-pseudo-element-contenturlimage

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proposed feature for `attr()` in [css-values-3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#attr-notation). The CSS would look like this:

```
.page-qr:before {
  content: attr(data-url url);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Unfortunately [there are no known implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers), so this still isn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon the same problem, but found a solution using **custom properties**. So we can pass any type that is allowed as a custom property value to it. Then you can absolute position it if that is what you look for.

You can use it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div style="--img-url: url('${imgUrl}')"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px; 
  content: var(--img-url); 
}
```

[See this post for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967890/css-set-background-image-by-data-image-attr/55270268#55270268)