# Div with CSS content, after pseudo element is not visible

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

I have a POC that I have to complete and I am only allowed to use CSS to update the styles of a product.  I have replaced one of the images of the product with a logo by using the CSS content attribute.

I have to add a simple string with a phone number to be shown after this logo.  I have tried to use the `:after` pseudo-element to do this.  This works only if the content of the `div` is empty (logo is removed).

```css
.demo {
  content: url('http://placehold.it/350x150')
}

.demo:after {
  content: 'test';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

I have tried changing the `display` to `inline-block` and hard coding the `height`and `width` for both rules.  Essentially everything I could find.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/qykbjznm/

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements

Comment: @pzworks: Not even close.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `content` property replaces all content within the element. By adding `content` to a non-pseudo selector, that content will replace the `::before` and `::after` pseudo selector.

So try doing this using the `content` property within the `::before` and `::after` pseudo selectors only.

```css
.demo:before {
     content: url('http://placehold.it/350x150')
}

.demo:after {
    content: 'some text';
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Just adding to the explanation, `content` only works on pseudo elements i.e `:before` and `:after`, so using `content` for `.demo` will fail.

Comment: @Mr.Alien if you look at the JSfiddle provided by OP, `content` is applied to a non-pseudo selector and is rendering as `content` would within `::before`/`::after` which is the root cause of the problem he was having.

Comment: @Mr. Alien: Correction, it's only *supported* on ::before and ::after. Some browsers *do* apply content to actual elements, but it's considered non-standard behavior.

Comment: @BoltClock My bad, what I meant was that you need to have `content` for pseudo elements, without them, it won't render. Was kinda FYI. Thanks though... @Jamy thanks you too for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

You could replace the background from the CSS and put it as an image in the HTML:

```css
.demo::after {
    content: 'test';
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <img src='http://placehold.it/350x150'/>
</div>
```

Or even do this:

```css
.demo {
     background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
     height:150px;
     width:350px;
}

.demo::after {
    content: 'test';
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

There are two different results.

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers apply the `content` property to actual elements, despite it [not being supported in CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#content). css-content-3 is expected to allow this, but until the level 3 spec becomes a standard, which realistically won't happen for another few years (especially considering it hasn't happened in the last *14* years), applying `content` to actual elements should be considered non-standard behavior.

When the value of the `content` property is an image, [that image is inserted as replaced content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978807/can-you-apply-a-width-to-a-before-after-pseudo-element-contenturlimage/14979383#14979383). And when this is applied to an actual element, this prevents the element from having `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. This is why your `::after` pseudo-element doesn't appear.

As mentioned, all you have to do is apply the image to the element's `::before` pseudo-element, not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have messed around with your JSFiddle a bit and I found that the only real way of making the phone number display below the current div is by creating another div:

```
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="demo2"></div>
<style>
  .demo {
    content: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    height:150px;
    width:350px;
  }

  .demo2:before {
    content: "test";
  }
</style>
```