# How can I alter the dimensions of an image in an animation? Specifically, an animation that starts from a text and goes to an image

Tags: html, css

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@keyframes animation {
 from {content: "The image is too large. How would I make it smaller in this animation?";}
 to {content: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/09/13/13/47/animal-7451969_960_720.jpg);}
}
.ani::before {
  animation: animation 5s linear 0s infinite none;
  content: "Wow";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="ani"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the image content (in the "to" section) to be a specific size without putting the animation in an image box (for the sake of the text it starts with). How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978807/can-you-apply-a-width-to-a-before-after-pseudo-element-contenturlimage)

You can use `background-image` however if this would work for you